# AT91SAM7X-EK Evaluation Board

Tags: c, linux, embedded, arm, processor

I just recentely started working with a new board: a AT91SAM7X-EK. I would like to get more information about the board's processor (AT91SAM7X256) and the board's flash. So I looked at a pretty detailed [data sheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel_32-bit-ARM7TDMI-Flash-Microcontroller_SAM7X512-256-128_Datasheet.pdf) and a [summary](http://www.atmel.com/Images/6120s.pdf) of the data sheet, but have been unsucessfull (so far) of finding the information I want. I would appreciate if anyone could help me on the following aspects of the board:

1. How do I connect to the board? Is it through ssh? If so, how is it possible to recuperate the board's IP address. I have an ethernet cable for the connection.
2. How do I load an application onto the board's flash? For example, I would like to cross compile (using a toolchain I've already installed - `arm-none-eabi`) a simple hello world program in C to load onto my board. How would I go about doing so?

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: There may be default firmware on the board which allows you to connect some other way, but most likely the usual way to connect while developing is via the JTAG connector.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thank you for your answer. I do have the JTAG connecter with a USB (as it suggests). How can I therefore connect to the board once I plug it in?

Comment: I don't know. It varies board-by-board. There should have been a DVD with the board. The data sheet says that this contains instructions for using the board with several different toolchains. I would recommend you start there.

Comment: The data sheet contains instructions or the DVD? If the former, which page exactly is that please? I've searched and can't seem to find it through the 600+ pages.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6195.pdf - Section 2.5

Comment: Thank you. I'm taking a look at it.

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel_32-bit-ARM7TDMI-Flash-Microcontroller_SAM7X512-256-128_Datasheet.pdf - Page 22 - "SAM-BA Boot Assistant" - Might be present on that board.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm taking a look at U-Boot as a bootloader and seeing how it can load my application onto the board.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I have successfully connected to the board using the SAM-ICE JTAG adapter. Do you happen to know or found out what kind of toolchain I can use to cross compile a hello world application (in C) that would be compatible with the board?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51441/discussion-between-dark-falcon-and-john-smith)

Comment: TBH, it's quite a heavy task just to get anything at all running on an embedded board if you are 'starting from scratch', even with a professional-level IDE, cross-compiler, board-support package, JTAG debugger etc.

Comment: I mean, for starters, where/what are you going to output 'Hello World' to?

Comment: @MartinJames To a terminal on the host machine it is connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board is supplied "bare-metal" - no code, no OS.  You will not be able to run Linux on an AT91SAM7X-EK - it has insufficient memory resources and rins at 30MHz tops (and has no MMU).

You need a hardware JTAG or DBGU interface device and a tool-chain that will work with it.

You should probably also be looking at the [datasheet for the board](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6195.pdf) itself.  From the *Getting Started* section of that:

> The AT91SAM7X-EK evaluation board is delivered with a DVD-ROM containing all necessary
>   information and step-by-step procedures for working with the most common
>   development tool chains. Please refer to this DVD-ROM, or to the AT91 web site,
>   http://www.atmel.com/products/AT91/, for the most up-to-date information on getting
>   started with the evaluation kit.

So start there.